# Is it a problem that a door installer cut out most of the trimmer studs?

Tags: doors, structural, installation, studs, cutting

My contractor cut the stud around the rough opening very aggressively to squeeze a wider door in, and I wonder how bad the damage is to the structure and what the consequences are.

Here are the details. My old door was 64” wide, but the new door ordered by the contractor mistakenly is 68”. Rather than replacing it with the correct width, he simply cut the stud around the rough opening and the jamb to make some room. I suppose there were two 2x4 studs on each side of the rough opening, and he almost removed one completely from each side. He also cut the jamb and the head of the door. Even with these cuttings, the door still could not fit in easily, thus he hammered it in as much as possible, but not completely. The brickmould of the door is not snug against the sheathing.

1

[image]

2
[image]
3
[image]
4
[image]
5
[image]
6
[image]
7
[image]
8
[image]
9
[image]
10
[image]
11
[image]
12
[image]
13
[image]
14
[image]
15
[image]
16
[image]
17
[image]
18
[image]

Comment: Is this still open? Run a drill into the side of the opening and see exactly how much wood is left. Sounds like the entire trimmer (header support) stud was removed, which could be a serious problem. Or not. Reducing the header may also have taken it out of spec.

Comment: We can't tell anything without knowing how much wood is left.

Comment: I definitely don't like how the head jamb was mangled. That could leave it saggy as a head jamb shouldn't be fastened to the framing.

Comment: Seems like it carries a floor load, but nothing from the roof (I want to putz around in an attic before asserting for sure). The lengths of the floor joists above the header are necessary information. Judging by Table R602.7(2) from below [IRC R602.7](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-6-wall-construction#IRC2021P2_Pt03_Ch06_SecR602.7), single jack studs are sufficient for 24 ft long joists and shorter. I suspect that the contractor removed a bunch of furring material that was installed inside the rough opening for the old door. The cross cuts into the jack studs are obnoxious

Comment: The cross cut on one of the bottom plates still looks oxidized, indicating furring on that side. The other side looks freshly cut, but the jack stud above it looks like somebody took a grinder to it or something. I'm not sure about that side. Ah, those are reciprocating saw marks. Maybe something structural was subtracted on that side. Nice images, dude.

Comment: Do you recall if they chopped an 1-1/2" or 3" chunk off of the 2x4 running along the floor on the one side with a fresh cut down there? Am I mistaken about the other side? Is that 2x4 running along the floor freshly cut also?

Comment: @isherwood No, it's not open now. Most of the trimmer studs were removed, only 1/2" left at most on each side.

Comment: @popham He cut about 1-1/2" on both sides.

Comment: You mean that the header only has 1/2" bearing on top of full thickness jack studs? And how long do the joists span from above the door to their other support? Is that a sleeping room above them?

Comment: @popham Which side looks oxidized, and which side looks fresh? Could you please refer with the photo number? "the header only has 1/2" bearing on top of full thickness jack studs": this is very likely, the jack studs after cutting only are only 1/2" thick at most, thus the header only has 1/2" bearing at most on top of each of them, unless there are sister jack studs. I don't know about the joist span or it's direction. Anywhere I can find the info? It's the hallway above the door, not a room.

Comment: At the bottom of image 6 is where I thought I saw the oxidized bottom plate. About 1 ft above the bottom plate, the side of the jack stud looks like it has the same oxidation, indicating that the reciprocating saw blade missed a little patch there. On the 1/2" thickness, did you drill or something? 1/2" thickness would be very, very unconventional. The joist span length running perpendicular to the header determines the load on the header. Typically there would be a load bearing wall carrying the other end of the joists. Maybe a carrier beam hidden in the ceiling.

Comment: @popham The darkness of the bottom plate was caused by water, but it is a fresh cut. Do you mean the red circle area by “About 1 ft above the bottom plate”? I think these are reciprocating saw marks just as the green circle. They appear darker because of the shadow of the Tyvek. I estimate the thickness by checking how much wood was cut off and from the hole in Image 3 for the other side in particular, and the estimations were also confirmed by the contractor.

Comment: @popham I’m not sure if the joists are parallel to the header or perpendicular. If the latter, there should be hidden beam in the ceiling which I cannot tell the position by simply looking at it. Anyway to the find out? Thank you.

Comment: If the joists run parallel to the header, then there's probably no weight to support (confirming that your roof's load goes into the side walls would indicate for sure that the header carries no load). Looking up from below, the header has two plies oriented vertically. That's the typical indicator for a structural header. Knocking on the ceiling like you're searching for a stud would be the least invasive method to confirm the joist orientation. Then look parallel to the door's wall in line with the joists for another wall within, say, 20 ft.

Comment: The middle section of roof that slopes down toward the street has a vertically oriented bit of wall. That's the likely location for an interior load bearing wall. I would expect the hidden beam to be located directly under that wall line.

Comment: So you measured that 1/2" at the thin spot created by their cross cuts? The thickness of the undamaged parts of the stud are 1-1/2"? At the top where they removed material from the stud directly below the header, what's the thickness there? About that 1/2"?

Comment: @popham The depth of the hold in image 3 is about 1/2", thus about 1-1/2" removed. I'm not sure what you mean by "The thickness of the undamaged parts of the stud are 1-1/2". From top to bottom, about 1-1/2" out of 2" are removed from the jack stud.

Comment: @popham I'm unable to check the house in person in the near future. Maybe I need structrual engineer?

Comment: Image 3 is zoomed in on the hole from image 4. Image 4 shows clean horizontal cuts ("crosscuts")a couple inches above and below the hole. Material between these cuts has been removed, making the jack stud thinner there. Is the 1/2" hole depth measured from the back of the hole to the face of the damaged material right beside the hole? Or is the 1/2" hole depth measured from the back of the hole to the face of the undamaged jack stud?

Comment: Judging by the roof's ridge running parallel to the street and that stairway immediately inside the door, I'm 90% sure that the header is load bearing. It's just foolish not to know with 100% certainty before exploring the area between jack studs and that header. Ignoring that 10%, just remove the drywall from the inside wall where the header bears on the stud. Confirming that there's a problem, I would figure out that 10% and then call a carpenter or handyman, not an engineer. If there's a problem, the hard part will be repairing without redoing the door.

Comment: @popham Thank you for the reply. I'm not sure which part of the jack stud is "undamaged", as it was cut from the top to the bottom, though the other area is smoother than the crosscut part. 1/2" was measured horizontally between red and green dots in Image 4.